# Can data processing time be estimated?

Tags: dataset, predictive-models

I'm curious if there are any analytical or empirical methods to estimate the time it would take to process a data set (grouping or various prediction algorithms).  Known variables would obviously include the size of the dataset, but also the types of variables (continuous/discrete), the number of factors for discrete variables, the amount of memory available, and processor power.

This sounds like a long shot to me, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes. You can use [asymptotic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) to determine how the algorithm's runtime scales as the size of all important variables goes to infinity. For most conventional algorithms this runtime is known (typically written O(...) where (...) is a function of the important variables). For many applications and datasets, this is sufficient to get a ballpark estimate of the run time (i.e. plug your values into the function, which gives you the number of steps required; divide by the speed of your processor in cycles/second; maybe multiply by one hundred as an upper bound guess at the constant factor)

If you need a tighter estimate, you can then run the algorithm for several smallish sample inputs, and use the average times on these small inputs to get a better estimate of the lower order terms and constants in the asymptotic runtime. Alternatively, you can find the paper where the algorithm was first introduced or analyzed (or find a good textbook written from a Computer Science prospective). Often this will furnish you with a more precise estimate.